# Status Bar not showing on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have the status bar set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and in all other devices (5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus) the status bar is showing in white text.  The background color of my app is black, so the status bar has a black background, thats why I need the status bar text to be white.

So only when I test on the 4S does the status bar text show as black. Is this a known bug? Is there any work around on making the 4S have the correct status bar style?

**This is why I have done**

in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

in each ViewController within my app I put this in viewDidLoad and add this method:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Also, in my info.plist I have this:

```
Status bar style = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

Comment: are you using autolayout or multiple storyboards?

Comment: I am using auto layout but only one storyboard.. and I have also set each view controller to have light content as the status bar style in interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) to YES in your Info.plist. (YES is the default, so you can also just leave this value out of your plist.)

Comment: Your a life saver.. I set it to NO and the status bar is showing up now.. Thanks!